# how to show buttons in bottom of the tablelayout?

Tags: android, tablelayout, ui-design

I have download sample tablelayout source code it's working fine. I am trying to show four image button in bottom of the table layout but still it,s not working.

Current image:
[image]

I am trying to show this 4 buttons in bottom of the table layout:
[image]

This is my code: i wish to merge my source code in my table layout bottom please help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ttt3"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bt_blue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ttt2"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bt_yellow"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ttt3"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ttt1"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
       android:background="@drawable/bt_green"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ttt2"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ttt0"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bt_red"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

table code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="Weather Table"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_span="6"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"
            android:text=""></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"
            android:text="Feb 7"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:text="Feb 8"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:text="Feb 9"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:text="Feb 10"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:text="Feb 11"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="Day High"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:text="28°F"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:text="26°F"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:text="23°F"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:text="17°F"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:text="19°F"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="Day Low"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:text="15°F"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:text="14°F"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:text="3°F"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:text="5°F"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:text="6°F"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:text="Conditions"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:src="@drawable/hot"></ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/pt_cloud"></ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:src="@drawable/snow"></ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:src="@drawable/lt_snow"></ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:src="@drawable/pt_sun"></ImageView>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want the buttons at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Please look my expecting screen shot. i am trying to create same design i Know table design but the bottom 4 buttons design how to merge in bottom of the table layout?

Comment: @RBalaji, there is a difference between bottom of screen and bottom of the table layout. Suppose the table layout takes up only half of the screen where should the buttons be? at the bottom of the screen or at the end of the table layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provded you want to put buttons at the bottom of the screen, you can have a setup like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:id="buttons">
        <!-- your buttons go here -->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TableLayout layout_height="match_parent" layout_above="buttons">
        <!-- your table content -->
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that this is pseudo-code. You will need to actually specify all the required attributes on the XML elements.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the it on the button of the screen just wrap the table inside an LinearLayout.
after the table is done you can add you Relative layout by copy & paste it or by using

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve using relative layout and by putting layout weight. Here is an example

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:id="@+id/biometric_layout">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"    
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/trans_Heading"
    android:id="@+id/headingRow"
    >   

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"    
    android:weightSum="100"    
    >

 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewDialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="false" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight = "70"
        > 

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
       <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ibTermsConditions"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:src="@drawable/bio_finger_scan_image" 
                />       
    </LinearLayout> 
  </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight = "30"
        >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="Back"        
        android:textSize="15sp" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"        
        android:text="Next>"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/btCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
     </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>     

    </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the button to be placed at the bottom of the screen replace your linear layout with relative layout and place the buttons in that.

```
    <RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout 
    layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
           <!-- Your Button is to be placed here -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableLayout>
//Your table contents
    </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```